# RxJS create new operator when to use the long way

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm trying to figure out when I need to use the **long** way, for example:

```
function mySimpleOperator(someCallback) {
   return Observable.create(subscriber => {
     var source = this;
     var subscription = source.subscribe(value => {
        subscriber.next(someCallback(value));
     },
     err => subscriber.error(err),
     () => subscriber.complete());
     return subscription;
   });
}
```

And when I can use the **shorter** way, for example:

```
 function mySimpleOperator(someCallback) {
    return this.map(val => someCallback(value));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use as much as possible operators provided by RxJS library and create your own then it is absolutely required. RxJS team put a lot of optimizations to the existing operators. Plus your new operator might be not compatible in future or might not get performance optimizations that RxJS team will add to the next release of the library.